# System.NotImplementedException al salvar datos en el DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Quiero salvar el **ID** del usuario que ha hecho login dentro de el **DB** en la columna **"CreatedBy"** en el **DB** todas la identidades creadas por el usuario tiene que tener el **ID** de dicho usuario que las creo, pero al hacer click en el boton **"Crear"** recibo una **System.NotImplementedException**, no tengo idea del por que.

Uso **Identity framework** con **ASP.net MVC 5** y **EF.**

Modelo **IdentityModel.cs**, metodo donde se encuetra el error:

```
   public static implicit operator string(ApplicationUser v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // aqui se encuentra la excepcion
    }
}
```

Metodo **Create()** del controllador **FitnessGoalController** creado desde el Modelo **FitnessGoals**, aqui es donde se trata de salvar el **ID** del usuario logueado en el DB:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Goal,StartDate,FinishDate,Weight")] FitnessGoals fitnessGoals)
    {

        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            fitnessGoals.CreatedBy = user;
            db.FitnessGoals.Add(fitnessGoals);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(fitnessGoals);
    }
```

Comment: Ese código lo pone por default Visual Studio y significa: "escriba aquí su lógica".

Comment: Cambia var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()); por var user = User.Identity.GetUserId(); por que por lo que veo quieres guardar solo el id no toda la entidad usuario

Comment: Lo cambie y ahora funciona, pero me quedo con la duda

Comment: que duda @BryanRomero ??

Comment: De porque usando user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()); me da el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te manda ese error por  que no has controlado las excepciones al guardar los datos en la base, tu error se encuentra al asignarle la variable `user` toda la entidad usuario que estas recuperando con `UserManager.FindById()` entonces lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar la linea:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

por la linea:

```
var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

para que al asignarle el valor de esta ultima el resultado sea el `string`  que contiene el Id del usuario y no toda la entidad entonces a la hora de guardar no detecte ese error y no te salga  que no has controlado las excepciones.